# На планшете приложение  работает, на смартфоне падает

Tags: android, java

Привет.

Есть код в `Activity`. Меняется фрагмент. Приложение работает на планшете, а на смартфоне падает. (см. строку с комментарием). `try/catch` ничего не показывает. Версия андроида на планшете 4.2, на смартфоне 4.4

В чём может быть дело? Код:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
    // fragment directly in the containing UI.
    View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);

    mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state for checked position.
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
    }

    Fragment f = map.get(mCurCheckPosition);
    f = new DeviceUARTFragment(getActivity() , ftD2xx);

    map.put(mCurCheckPosition, f);
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", mCurCheckPosition);
    f.setArguments(args);

    currentFragment = f;

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.details, f);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit(); /* на этой строчке приложение падает*/

    old_index = currect_index;
}
```

**Обновление**

В Манифесте прописан android:targetSdkVersion="19" - сделал, не помогло.

Ссылка на логи: https://yadi.sk/i/bl425-WBcoUjX (не помещается текст здесь).

Comment: Лог падения в студию.

Comment: А в Манифесте прописан android:targetSdkVersion="19" (4.4 Андроид)?

Comment: @gcoder, в чём отличие таких лэйаутов?

Comment: @olegall, [вот][1], ну или [вот][2].


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
  [2]: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/189-urok-115-odno-prilozhenie-na-raznyh-ekranah

Answer (score 1):

Для обычных телефонов слои нужно хранить в папках:

- /res/layout/
- /res/layout-land/

// первая папка для портретной ориентации, вторая для альбомной.

Для планшетов 7 и 10 дюймов папки будут следующие:

- /res/layout-sw600dp/
- /res/layout-sw600dp-land/

и

- /res/layout-sw700dp/
- /res/layout-sw700dp-land/

соответственно.

Если рассмотреть на примере слоя `my_super_layout.xml`, то его расположение в папках будет таким:

- (телефон) - /res/layout/my_super_layout.xml
- (телефон) - /res/layout-land/my_super_layout.xml
- (7" планшет) - /res/layout-sw600dp/my_super_layout.xml
- (7" планшет) - /res/layout-sw600dp-land/my_super_layout.xml
- (10" планшет) - /res/layout-sw700dp/my_super_layout.xml
- (10" планшет) - /res/layout-sw700dp-land/my_super_layout.xml

Папки нужно просто создать и поместить в них слои. Слои могут быть и абсолютно идентичными, но наличие папок даст зеленый свет в Google Play, который будет напоминать постоянно о введении поддержки широкоэкранных гаджетов.

Также, по правилам этики, хорошо иметь папки иконок под разные экраны. Но это не тема Вашего вопроса, поэтому описывать не буду.

**UPD1:**

Добавь в манифесте следующее:

```
<uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

// Это даст возможность запускаться на Android 3.0 - Android 5.0.

И после чего именно вылетает приложение на смартфоне? Я бы еще отследил при помощи собственных логов. 
Расставь в коде

```
Log.v/i/e/w/d("myLogs", "после действия чего-то");
```

`v/i/e/w/d` - разные типы сообщений. Выбрать нужно одно.
А в LogCat создать нужно будет фильтр с параметром "myLogs". В итоге в фильтре можно будет увидеть, что выполнено, а после чего "крашится"/crash приложение. А так же можно вывести отдельно фильтр с "errors" (есть в выпадающем списке).

Здесь информация по Log - [кликни по мне](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) //Google источник

Answer (score 0):

`<telepat_mode>` Для смартфона используется layout, где не задан `view` c `id details<telepat_mode/>`

**Обновление**

Например, layout для активити - layout.xml, лежит в папке /layout и  используется для смартфона. А в папке `/layout-large` лежит файл с таким же именем `layout.xml`, но используется для больших экранов (для планшета).

Comment: ><telepat_mode> Для смартфона используется layout, где не задан view c id details<telepat_mode/>

Можно про это подробнее?

Comment: @olegall, Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Проверь В манифесте Таргет, или если ты делал для планшета и для смартфона отдельные лайот, то проверь их. Может, активити у вас есть другой, и вы забыли прописать в манифесте? Пробуй оставить только /layout с main.xml. А лучше весь код в Пастебин, там и видно будет.

Comment: Может, активити у вас есть другой, и вы забыли прописать в манифесте?  
Пробуй оставить только /layout с main.xml.  
А лучше весь код в Пастебин, там и видно будет.

Comment: Я не делал отдельных лэйаутов. Их обязательно делать?

Comment: @olegall, не обязательно. Система растянет на весь экран тот слой, что найдет. Но лучше делать отдельно папки со слоями для разных диагоналей экранов, так как не всегда все смотрится на широком экране красиво.

Comment: Надо как-то по особому прописывать xml теги для маленьких экранов телефона?

Comment: @olegall, ответил ниже. Такая большая запись не влезла бы в комментарий.